# Relación Modelo Django

Tags: django, django-models

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy creado un modelo al cual llame `Evento`, este se relaciona con un modelo llamado `PersonaNatural` por medio de una tabla intermedia `AsistentesEvento` necesito que a un evento puedan asistir muchas persona y que una persona pueda ir a muchos eventos pero que solo pueda registrase una sola vez por evento tal como lo hace el `ManyToMany` de Django. A continuación mi código.

```
class Evento(RegistroTiempo):
    # Campos del modelo

class PersonaNatural(RegistroTiempo):
    # Campos del modelo

class AsistentesEvento(RegistroTiempo):
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Evento, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('evento'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    invitado = models.ForeignKey(PersonaNatural, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('invitado'),
                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    asistio = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('asistió'))
```

La cuestión es que de esta forma una persona puede registrarse varias veces como asistente a un evento. Como puedo limitar esto a una sola vez por evento?

Comment: Entonces pon una relación `OneToOneField` en `evento` y en `invitado`.

Comment: Aplique los cambios pero no resulto como quería, edite la pregunta para que se entienda mejor lo que necesito hacer.

Comment: Necesitas que solo una persona sea el asistente de un evento(`AsistenteEvento`) verdad?

Comment: No, necesito varios asistentes por cada evento, pero que una persona no aparezcan 2 veces en la lista por decirlo de alguna manera.

Comment: Entonces pon una relacion `OneToOneField` en evento y una relacion `ManyToMany` en invitado, y para evitar que se repitan tienes que hacerlo en la vista, antes de crear una instancia de dicho modelo, has algo asi: `if request.user not  in AsistentesEvento.invitado.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que una persona pueda registrarse solo una vez en un evento puedes usar la clase [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) en el modelo `AsistentesEvento` el código quedaria asi:

```
class AsistentesEvento(RegistroTiempo):
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Evento, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('evento'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    invitado = models.ForeignKey(PersonaNatural, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('invitado'),
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    asistio = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('asistió'))

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['evento', 'invitado'], name='evento_invitado ')
    ]
```

De esta manera una persona solo puede registrarse solo una vez en un evento